# Force flow failure email

Tags: visual-workflow

Does anyone know how to force a flow to fail and generate the detailed interview email? I used to create an email object with no recipients to get that.  I really liked to use it while developing/debugging longer flows.  The new designer must check for nulls and not generate the failure email.  I would like to force that when needed.

Comment: why not divide by a variable and pass in the variable as zero?

Comment: Excellent!  Thanks.

Comment: another approach is to insert a record with a required field missing;